# Does a Trumpet card count as following suit?

Tags: trumpet

[Trumpet](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/352/trumpet) includes three "trumpet" cards *without a suit* that always trump any other card.  However, the rules aren't particularly clear on whether they are truly "wild" in the sense that they could count as a card of any suit.  In particular, if you have another card of the suit that has been led, are you allowed to play a trumpet card instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In most games with a trump suit, you must follow with a card of the suit that has been led, unless you are void in that suit (have no cards of that suit), at which point you may play a trump card. Given that, I would assume the rules in Trumpet are the same, and you cannot play a Trumpet unless you're void in the suit led.

[This thread on BoardGameGeek](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/419412/clarification-about-play-of-trumpet-cards) agrees, so I'd say it's fairly common to play by that rule, even if the original rules are unclear.

Comment: Trumpet does have the rule that you must follow suit, but the trumpet cards have no suit.  Calling them "wild" has led players to believe that they're allowed to count as the led suit.  Do any other games have both trump suits and suitless cards?

Comment: @eswald Yes, for instance Tarot has 4 suits (cup, rods, swoards, and coins) plus 21 trump cards with no suit (or sometimes considered to be a "trump" suit). Most trick-taking games played with tarot cards require you to play on-suit, and may only play trumps if you are void in the suit.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know this particular game but from my experiences with various card games trumps are rarely considered matching a suit.

In most games one of the following scenarios is used:

1. Playing a card of the trump suit is not considered to be "following suit" and forbidden as long as one still has cards of the suit that was lead. See [Wizard](http://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/1465/wizard).
2. Playing a card of the trump suit is not considered to be "following suit" but explicitly allowed. See [Jass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jass).